# How can I properly display German characters in HTML?

Tags: html, unicode, localization

My pages contain German characters and I have typed the text in between the 
HTML tag, but the browser views some characters differently. Do I need to include anything in HTML to properly display German characters?

```
<label> ausgefüllt </label>
```

Comment: could you provide the german text please and indicate which browsers

Comment: <label>ausgefüllt<label> ,I am testing in FF v3.0.5

Comment: It would be nice if you provide this information in the question text, so everybody can see it without reading the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It seems you need some basic explanations about something that unfortunately even most programmers don't understand properly.

Files like your HTML page are saved and transmitted over the Internet as a sequence of bytes, but you want them displayed as characters. In order to translate bytes into characters, you need a set of rules called a [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Unfortunately, there are many different character encodings that have historically emerged to handle different languages. Most of them are based on the American [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding, but as soon as you have characters outside of ASCII such as [German umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut), you need to be very careful about which encoding you use.

The source of your problem is that in order to correctly decode an HTML file, the browser needs to know which encoding to use. You can tell it so in several ways:

- [The "Content-Type" HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset)
- [The HTML META tag](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-uncovered.html#content-type)
- The [XML encoding attribute](http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm#enc_howspecifyfordoc) if you use [XHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)

So you need to **pick one encoding, save the HTML file using that encoding, and make sure that you declare that encoding in at least one of the ways listed above** (and if you use more than one make damn sure they agree). As for what encoding to use, Germans often use [ISO/IEC 8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15), but [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is increasingly becoming the norm, and can handle any kind of non-ASCII characters at the same time.

Comment: You should alter the order: 1. HTTP header field, 2. XML declaration, 3. HTML META element. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.2.2 and http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding

Comment: UTF-8 is actually quite common in Germany now and can make all the difference when using German text. If  ISO/IEC 8859-15, doesn't work you should definitely try UTF-8 as the next option.

Comment: @PhillHealey 6 years later again, I'd say UTF-8 should now normally be the first thing to use.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt 11 hours later... Yes, I agree. ;-)

Answer (score 37):

UTF-8 is your friend.

Try

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and check which encoding your webserver sends in the header.

If you use PHP, you can send your own headers in this way (you have to put this before any other output):

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
```

Also doublecheck that you saved your document in UTF-8.

Comment: I have already added in My head tag,Still i got the hidden character

Comment: then your document is probably not in fact saved in UTF-8

Comment: You need the proper header to be sent from the webserver. The META tag won't be enough

Comment: Explanation: originally, it was intended that the webserver would parse the file and set its headers according to the <META HTTP-EQUIV="..."> tags, but webservers generally don't, and it's not specified how the browser should behave if they disagree.

Comment: @brazzy: it is specified in detail: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#spec-char-encoding and there are a few FAQ/QA articles on W3C website about this.

Answer (score 11):

Try the solution in blog post *[German characters encoding issue](http://allinoneissues.blogspot.jp/2012/05/german-characters-encoding-issue.html)*  (2012-05-10):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `&uuml;` (ü) and `&Uuml;` (Ü)?

You can find how to type other letters [here](http://lookuptables.com/).

Comment: that's massively impractical given how common these are going to be, he shouldn't and doesn't have to encode like this

Comment: Maybe, but this is how code my homepages with Swedish characters.

Comment: It's a workaround, but fortunately no longer necessary, if you specify the correct encoding. Sorry for the downvote, but there are much better solutions around.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that. I guess I'm one of those who brazzy is reffering to two posts below. :/

Answer (score 3):

Declare `<META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

and when saving the file, for example in notepad, choose the save as to be UTF-8 and not just .txt.

This should render the characters ok.

Answer (score 3):

you may try utf8_encode() or utf8_decode()  functions.Check if any of these works.

For example `<?php echo utf8_encode('ausgefüllt'); ?>`

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a character encoding issue, in that the file is saved as a different character encoding to what the webserver is saying it is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the use of HTML entities (like %uuml;), they are only needed when there is something wrong with your characterset.

In short:

The RIGHT way is to fix your characterset.

The EASY way is to just use entities. You may not ever see any problems with this.

Tracking down characterset error can be very difficult. If you give us an URL where we can see the problem, we can probably give you a good hint where to look.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

save as your file with UTF8, and use this META:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
```