# WooCommerce Shop is replacing special character

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I created some custom tabs for my WooCommerce page, which includes the name **Größe**, which means sizes in German. The font I'm using is futura-pt, loaded via typekit and the font includes the German letter **ß**. But in the frontend it's changed by **double ss**, so instead of **Größe** it's **Grösse**. How can I fix that, to get the ß displayed.

That's the code I'm working with inside my functions.php. I also tried to replace it with the html tag `&szlig;`, with no effects. Why I'm also confused is, that the third letter **ö** is also a special character, but that one works perfectly, without doing something.

```
if ( ! empty( $product_benefits ) )
    $tabs['size_tab'] = array(
        'title'    => __( 'Größen', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority' => 50,
        'callback' => 'benefits_product_tab_content'
    );
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: Is it possible you have `text-transform: uppercase` on the text? This would be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099163/how-can-i-prevent-the-browser-from-changing-%C3%9F-to-ss

Comment: I think it's time for a coffee break. Thx made. That was the problem

Comment: Converted to answer, feel free to accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uppercase of ß is SS – if your element has `text-transform: uppercase`, that would cause this transformation.

See [How can I prevent the browser from changing ß to ss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099163/how-can-i-prevent-the-browser-from-changing-%C3%9F-to-ss)