# php ë is being displayed as u00eb

Tags: php, character

In my DB I save some keywords with special characters. Currently when I have words with **ë** it's being displayed as **u00eb**.

Example: cli**ë**nten is being displayed as cli**u00eb**nten . I've got the following code that displays the keyword:

```
$professional_focus = '';
$res = json_decode(get_user_meta($curauth->ID, 'professional_focus', true));

if ($res) {
    $professional_focus .= '<strong>Aandachtsgebied(en)</strong><br />';
    foreach ($res as $focusterm) {
        $professional_focus .=  ''.$focusterm.', ';
    }
}
$professional_focus = substr($professional_focus, 0, -2);

<p>
    <?php echo ($professional_focus) ? $professional_focus : '';?>
</p>
```

How can I display the keywords correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423693/how-can-i-properly-display-german-characters-in-html

Comment: How is your database encoding? Utf8 ?
Which PHP version do you use, do you use andy framework?

Comment: Hi Ann, database is UTF8 encoded, PHP 5.7 and not using a framework. It's just a Wordpress website outputting a JSON string.