# Q: Why get jQuery datepicker months with umlauts displayed wrong in Wildfly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jboss, wildfly

I'm running Wildfly 15 and serving a HTML page with a header like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
```

Special characters like german umlauts which are direct content of this page are displayed correctly.

A jQuery datepicker works not so well, the month 'März' gets broken at the umlaut.

Same happens with other JS resources containing umlauts:

```
alert('öäü');
```

Is displayed as '���';

All files in the project are saved as ISO-8859-15 (legacy reasons, cannot be changed!).

Obviously Wildfly is serving the JSs as UTF-8 :-(

I tried setting encoding in standalone-full.xml

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" url-charset="ISO-8859-15" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
    <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" url-charset="ISO-8859-15" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
 ...
 <servlet-container name="default" default-encoding="ISO-8859-15" use-listener-encoding="true">
```

This had no effect on the problem, though.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? ;-)

Best regards

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to localize the `datepicker` component while initializing? If not please refer [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization)

Comment: yes, the datepicker is correctly localized: $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['de']);

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423693/how-can-i-properly-display-german-characters-in-html)

Comment: see above - the meta tag declares the ISO-8859 encoding already

Comment: but actually this is exactly my problem: the meta tag sets encoding as ISO-8859, but the Content-Type HTTP header is UTF-8. I tried to set Wildfly encoding in standalong-full.xml (see my question above), but this does not seem to work.

What am I missing here?